# Java on iPhone or iPad

Tags: java, iphone, ipad, jsp, applet

They say Java is not supported on iPhone or iPad. Does that mean websites with JSP as its server-side scripting language would not function properly on those devices? Or just do they only mean to say...let's say Java applet? There's not much information about it out there. I'm not even sure if those devices still don't support Java. The latest official announcement I found dated a few years back.

---

How dumb of me to have had asked this. Of course, since it's server-side, it doesn't care if the Java VM is present or not in iPhone. Doh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java applets run in the browser and aren't supported on iOS. JSP pages run on the server and generate the HTML which is perfectly compatible with iOS.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need Java at all on the iPad to see the content generated by JSP files.

JSP files are executed on the server, and generate (usually) HTML content that can be seen on an iPad. Also, JavaScript  works fine on an iPad, and there is no relation between Java and JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 1):

JSP is a server-side language, so it is never actually seen by the client. This will work.

A Java applet is something that is run by the client, and these will not work on iOS devices.